Why can't my C++ code finish compiling in g++ 9.4, but other versions do
I tested the code in linux g++ (GCC) 8.2.0, g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, and all of them can be compiled, but it fails to compile in g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0. Does anyone know why? I have a feeling that there are no errors in this code：
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <queue>

class Foo
{
public:
        void test(std::any a)
        {
                int val = std::any_cast<int>(a);
                std::cout << val << std::endl;
        }
};

using FUNC = void(Foo::*)(std::any);

std::queue<std::function<void(void)>> queue;

void enquee(Foo* foo, FUNC f, std::any a)
{
        queue.push(std::bind(f, foo, a));
        queue.front()();
        queue.pop();
}

int main(void)
{
        std::any a = 1;
        Foo f;
        enquee(&f, &Foo::test, a);
}

Confusing error message in 9.4.0
usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&> >':
/usr/include/c++/9/any:181:58:   required by substitution of 'template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >::value, bool>::type <anonymous>, typename std::enable_if<(! std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp>::value), bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&; _Tp = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >; typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >::value, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>; typename std::enable_if<(! std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp>::value), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from 'struct std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:901:12:   required from 'struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, true>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:907:12:   required from 'struct std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:231:42:   required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0; _Head = Foo*; _Tail = {std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:983:17:   required from 'std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&&) [with _Functor = void (Foo::*)(std::any); _Bound_args = {Foo*, std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:252:39:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:223:19:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:675:34:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]'
kesan.cpp:22:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12: error: incomplete type 'std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >' used in nested name specifier
  131 |     struct __and_<_B1, _B2>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >':
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:150:27:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
/usr/include/c++/9/any:192:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&; _Tp = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >; typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from 'struct std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:901:12:   required from 'struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, true>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:907:12:   required from 'struct std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:231:42:   required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0; _Head = Foo*; _Tail = {std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:983:17:   required from 'std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&&) [with _Functor = void (Foo::*)(std::any); _Bound_args = {Foo*, std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:252:39:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:223:19:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:675:34:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]'
kesan.cpp:22:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:136:12: error: incomplete type 'std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >' used in nested name specifier
  136 |     struct __and_<_B1, _B2, _B3, _Bn...>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >':
/usr/include/c++/9/any:192:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&; _Tp = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >; typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from 'struct std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:901:12:   required from 'struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, true>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:907:12:   required from 'struct std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:231:42:   required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0; _Head = Foo*; _Tail = {std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:983:17:   required from 'std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&&) [with _Functor = void (Foo::*)(std::any); _Bound_args = {Foo*, std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:252:39:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:223:19:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:675:34:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]'
kesan.cpp:22:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:150:27: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, const std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
  150 |     inline constexpr bool __and_v = __and_<_Bn...>::value;
      |                           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >':
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:136:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:150:27:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
/usr/include/c++/9/any:192:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Tp = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >; typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from 'struct std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:231:42:   required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0; _Head = Foo*; _Tail = {std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:983:17:   required from 'std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&&) [with _Functor = void (Foo::*)(std::any); _Bound_args = {Foo*, std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:252:39:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:223:19:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:675:34:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]'
kesan.cpp:22:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:142:31: error: incomplete type 'std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&>' used in nested name specifier
  142 |     : public __bool_constant<!bool(_Pp::value)>
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >':
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:136:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:150:27:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
/usr/include/c++/9/any:192:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Tp = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >; typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from 'struct std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:231:42:   required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0; _Head = Foo*; _Tail = {std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:983:17:   required from 'std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&&) [with _Functor = void (Foo::*)(std::any); _Bound_args = {Foo*, std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:252:39:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:223:19:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:675:34:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]'
kesan.cpp:22:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >'
  131 |     struct __and_<_B1, _B2>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >':
/usr/include/c++/9/any:192:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Tp = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >; typename std::enable_if<__and_v<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp> > >, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:883:12:   required from 'struct std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&>'
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:131:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >'
/usr/include/c++/9/any:181:58:   required by substitution of 'template<class _ValueType, class _Tp, class _Mgr, typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >::value, bool>::type <anonymous>, typename std::enable_if<(! std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp>::value), bool>::type <anonymous> > std::any::any(_ValueType&&) [with _ValueType = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Tp = std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>; _Mgr = std::any::_Manager_external<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >; typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_constructible<_Tp, _ValueType&&> >::value, bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>; typename std::enable_if<(! std::__is_in_place_type<_Tp>::value), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:231:42:   required from 'constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0; _Head = Foo*; _Tail = {std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:983:17:   required from 'std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&&) [with _Functor = void (Foo::*)(std::any); _Bound_args = {Foo*, std::any}]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:252:39:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:223:19:   required from 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_init_functor(std::_Any_data&, _Functor&&) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>]'
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:675:34:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (Foo::*(Foo*, std::any))(std::any)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]'
kesan.cpp:22:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:150:27: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__and_<std::is_copy_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> >, std::__not_<std::is_constructible<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>, std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any>&&> >, std::__not_<std::__is_in_place_type<std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::any> > > >'
  150 |     inline constexpr bool __and_v = __and_<_Bn...>::value;
      |

I tested the code in linux g++ (GCC) 8.2.0, g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0,and all of them can be compiled.

What options and flags do you pass to GCC when building? Please show us the complete command-line. I'm asking because you use some features that was added in later C++ standards, but which is invalid in the earlier standard used by not only version 9.4 but also in version 8.2. Both those gives me errors.

The latest releases of the Big Three seem to agree this code compiles without error: https://godbolt.org/z/adGf4qGjG. This seems like a compiler/library bug in GCC 9.4 that was fixed.

using the command line: g++ --std=c++17 -o test test.cpp

Congratulations, you found a bug in the compiler and/or the standard library implementation. It existed already from GCC version 9.1 up to version 9.4, and was fixed for version 9.5. The only solution is to not use the non-working versions of GCC.

clean godbolt with repro: https://godbolt.org/z/6xWbjzszf

BUG report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90415
